# How to write JSON to Event Hub correctly

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-eventhub

I'm batching serialized records (in a JArray) to send to Event Hub. When I'm writing the data to Event Hubs it seems to be inserting extra speech marks around the JSON i.e. what is written `"{"myjson":"blah"}"` not `{"myjson":"blah"}` so downstream I'm having trouble reading it.

Based on this [guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/#event-serialization), I must convert JSON to string and then use GetBytes to pass it into an EventData object. I suspect my attempt at following this guidance is where my issue is arising.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public static class EventDataTransform
{
    public static EventData ToEventData(dynamic eventObject, out int payloadSize)
    {
        string json = eventObject.ToString(Formatting.None);
        payloadSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json);
        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        var eventData = new EventData(payload)
        {
        };
        return eventData;
    }
}
```

**How should an item from a JArray containing serialized data be converted into the contents of an EventData message?**

---

Code call location - used in batching upto 256kb parcels

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
        var batch = new List<EventData>(_allEvents.Count);
        var batchSize = 0;
        for (int i = _lastBatchedEventIndex; i < _allEvents.Count; i++)
        {
            dynamic evt = _allEvents[i];
            int payloadSize = 0;
            var eventData = EventDataTransform.ToEventData(evt, out payloadSize);
            var eventSize = payloadSize + EventDataOverheadBytes;
            if (batchSize + eventSize > MaxBatchSizeBytes)
            {
                break;
            }

            batch.Add(eventData);
            batchSize += eventSize;
        }
        _lastBatchedEventIndex += batch.Count();
        _currentBatch = batch;
        return _currentBatch.Count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `ToEventData()` called?

Comment: Added to question. I'm also looking at whether JArray is the right structure for an array of complete JSON docs FWIW or whether some other object might be better for processing entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the JArray already contains serialized objects (strings). Calling `.ToString(Formatting.None)` will serialize it again a second time (wrapping it in quotes).

Interestingly enough, if you call `.ToString()` without passing in a `Formatting`, it would not serialize it again.

This fiddle demonstrates this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/H4p6KL